# laravel form not going to controller on submit

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravelcollective

I am using laravel collective form but on submit it just reload and stays on same page. 
It is not going to the controller method provided in action attribute.

Here is my form code

```
 {!! Form::open(['action' => 'UsrController@store', 'method'=>'POST']) !!}
    <div class="form-group">


        {{Form::label('ph_no','Phone Number')}}
        {{Form::text('ph_no','',['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'+92 3342079421'])}}
        <br>
        {{Form::label('user_type_id','User Type')}}
        <br>
        {{Form::select('user_type_id',$user_array,null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Please Select a User Type']
        )}}
        <br>
        {{Form::label('country_id','Country')}}
        <br>
        {{Form::select('country_id',$country_array,null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Please Select a Country']
        )}}

    </div>

    {{Form::submit('Submit',['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

UsrController store method reference:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'name'=>'required',
        'email'=>'required',
        'user_type_id'=>'required'
    ]);

    $use= new User();
    $use->phno=$request->input('ph_no');
    $use->user_type_id=$request->input('user_type_id');
    $use->country_id=$request->input('country_id');
    $use->save();
    return redirect('/User')->with('success','User Created!');
}
```

**I am using laravel collective v.6.0**

Edit:

Route:

```
Route::resource('Usr','UsrController');
```

html generated for the form:

```html
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/final/hire/public/Usr" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="8QMxOxKHVs4LPy0SZ1NN6KgKevMRJwvPa4jC9lEj">
 <div class="form-group">
<label for="ph_no">Phone Number</label>
 <input placeholder="+92 3342079421" name="ph_no" type="text" value="" id="ph_no" class="form-control"> 
<br> 
<label for="user_type_id">User Type</label> 
<br> 
<select id="user_type_id" name="user_type_id" class="form-control"><option selected="selected" value="">Please Select a User Type</option><option value="1">Poster</option><option value="2">Worker</option></select> 
<br> 
<label for="country_id">Country</label> 
<br> 
<select id="country_id" name="country_id" class="form-control"><option selected="selected" value="">Please Select a Country</option><option value="1">Pakistan</option></select>
</div> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant routes to the question?

Comment: @Ayrton have added route info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that it wasn't a typo in the code you posted, I would suggest switching over to `Route::resource('User','UserController');` and also updating the name of the controller to `UserController`.

In the store method you're redirecting to `'/User'` but that route wouldn't be created from the route snippet you posted.

Edit:

It looks like it's failing validation. name and email are required, but not present in the form.

Comment: this is not the issue, my other forms are also not submitting such as project form

Comment: can you post the html that is generated for the form as well?

Comment: it is not going to the store method so redirecting is not an issue here. but i hv another route named user

Comment: this could be an issue lemme check my message file

Comment: there was a connecting issue with the messages also a timestamp problem due to which it was not submitting